# Changing function variables through local function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change a variable in function through its helper function.
I tried the following:

```
def f():
    e = 70
    print(e) # prints 70
    def helper(e):
        print(e) # prints 70
        e = 100
        print(e) # prints 100
    helper(e) #function called to change e
    print(e)  # Still prints 70 :( Why?

f() #prints 70, 70, 100, 70
```

Why does it not change the value of e (I passed it as parameter and python doesn't copy values too, so value of e in f should be changed)?
Also how can I get the required result?

Comment: This is because of scoping: e outside of `helper` is a different variable than e inside. In your case helper just uses e to print sth which is based on e, but afterwards the program continues happily with the only e it has. If you want to receive the result of helper, you should add a return Statement to helper, so that it gives back its result and then write `e = helper(e)`

Answer (score 0):

`e` in function `f` is local to `f` and you passed argument `e`. But inside `helper` when you did `e=100` it is another local variable within the scope of `helper`. So, you should return the value from helper and update e.

you should do this,

```
def f():
    e = 70
    print(e) 
    def helper(d):
        print(d) 
        e = 100
        print(e)
        return e # prints 100
    e = helper(e) 
    print(e)  

f()
```